# Pandas - KeyError when dropping columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, drop, del

I have df (attached).
I want to drop one column "image" but I keep getting KeyError 'image' not found in axis.

Code used for dropping column:

monarchs_df = df.drop(columns =['image'], axis=1, inplace=True)
or
monarchs_df = df.drop(['image'], axis=1, inplace=True)

still error. What am I doing wrong?

different approach to the code - still the same error

Comment: First, your post seems to be missing lots of things - there is no df in the message, and you say at the end 'different approach...same error' but there is no different approach shown.
Second - try your code from the beginning without using `inplace=True`. When you use `inplace=True`, it will change the original `df` and it will return `None`. That is, `monarchs_df` will be `None`, not the changed dataframe. If you run the code multiple times then, you'll be dropping the column in the first run and then trying to drop it again after it has been dropped

Comment: please show your df

Comment: sorry for missing info, my first approach to pandas and questions here. Problem sorted: code change to: monarch_df.drop(['image', axis=1, inplace=True